# Getting file from FTP with space in filename VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, ftp, uri, space

I'm lookin for a solution for the  problem, that I cannot download a file with a space in its name.

Edit: I found out that the ftp server is running on linux and my connection code need to set to utf-8? can that be true?

I tried to  pass different version of the filename:

Name with Space

Name%20with%20Space

Name/ with/ Space

Name/with/Space

Name"/"with"/"Space

but nothing worked. Here is my code

```
   Dim ftpRequest As FtpWebRequest = System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(myFTPPath & My ftp name with space )

       ftpRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(User, Password)

Dim ftpResponse As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = Nothing
            Dim iTries As Integer = 0
            Do While (IsNothing(ftpResponse) And iTries < 10)
                iTries += 1
                ftpResponse = getResponse(ftpRequest)
            loop
 ..........
 ...........
 ...........


Private Shared Function getResponse(ByRef request As FtpWebRequest) As FtpWebResponse
    Dim res As Boolean = False
    Dim response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = Nothing
    Try
        response = request.GetResponse
    Catch ex As WebException

        If ex.Status = WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure Then
            response = Nothing
        End If
    End Try
    Return response
End Function
```

Anybody knows a working solution?

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried cover whole path "" marks?

```
Dim ftpRequest As FtpWebRequest = System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create("""ftp://example.com/directory with withespace/file with whitespace.txt""")
```

As you suppose this will produce

```
"ftp://example.com/directory with withespace/file with whitespace.txt"
```

string.